# Which base of numerical system have $\frac 15 = 0.33333\ldots$?

Tags: number-systems

Which base of numerical system have $\frac{1}{5} = 0.33333\ldots$?

I need assistance in solving this one.

Comment: http://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-decimal-hexadecimal-converter.html is worth a look. It offers decimal, binary and hex conversions. It might help you see the relationships, ex, enter binary .010101010101 and see what this is in decimal.

Answer (score 28):

If we are working in base $b$ (we must have $b\gt3$), then $0.3333\ldots$ is
$$0.3333\ldots = \frac{3}{b} + \frac{3}{b^2} + \frac{3}{b^3}+\cdots$$
Since
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3}{b^n} = \frac{3}{b}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{b^n} = \frac{3}{b}\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{b}}\right) =\frac{3}{b-1},$$
then...

Answer (score 27):

Hint: if we multiply $0.33333\ldots$ by $5$ then we get $0.(15)(15)(15)(15)(15)\ldots$. Compare that to what happens when we multiply the same by $3$: $0.99999\ldots$, and its interpretation in decimal.

Answer (score 12):

A reworking of Arturo's answer: let $x=0.333\dots$, let the base be $b$, then $$bx=3.333\dots$$ so $bx-x=(3.333\dots)-(0.333\dots)$ and you can take it from there.

Comment: That should be $bx-x$, not $bx-b$.

Comment: @jwodder correction made, thanks very much.

Comment: So irrespective of the Base, the decimal shifts to the right when number is multiplied by the base?

Comment: @Sid, yes --- just think about what it means to write a number to a base.